# not overlap SliverToBoxAdapter with a transparent SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible for a `SliverToBoxAdapter` to not be overlaped with a transparent`SliverAppBar` when scrolled upon?

Or give up on using `SliverAppBar` and just use `AppBar` instead?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Image(
        image: bkgImage,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      ),
      Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
              pinned: _pinned,
              snap: _snap,
              floating: _floating,
              expandedHeight: 160,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                expandedTitleScale: 1.6,
                titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                title: Text('Panahon'),
              ),
            ),
            
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Card(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Card(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Card(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Card(),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Card(),
                ),
              ]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

[image]

[image]

The goal is this:

[image]

Comment: You can try `pinned:true`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yup its already `pinned:true`

Answer (score 0):

#### Precious view:

To get actual effect, we can use  `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`. Concept is we need to pass image itself [both image must be screen size].

```dart
class MySliverHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double _maxExtent = 160;
  final VoidCallback onActionTap;

  final Image imageWidget;

  MySliverHeaderDelegate({
    required this.onActionTap,
    required this.imageWidget,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    debugPrint(shrinkOffset.toString());
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: imageWidget,
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Text(
              'Panahon',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // here provide actions
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: onActionTap,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => _maxExtent;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant MySliverHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate != this;
  }
}
```

And use

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageWidget = Image.asset(
      "assets/images/image01.png",
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    );
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          imageWidget,
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  delegate: MySliverHeaderDelegate(
                      imageWidget: imageWidget,
                      onActionTap: () {
                        debugPrint("on Tap");
                      }),
                ),
              //.....
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

#### Others way to handle this situation

Being `SliverAppBar`'s `backgroundColor:Colors.transparent` you are able to see though appbar.

If you provide your preferable color, that will fix the issue in this case, but you will not get background effect on appBar.

```dart
SliverAppBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.green, // the one you like
```

For your case, you can use `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar` instead of using `SliverAppBar`. It will still block the background on scroll and it won't get that much height.

```dart
CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  largeTitle: const Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: SizedBox(
      child: Text('Panahon'),
    ),
  ),
  trailing: IconButton(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
),
```

Comment: The background is an image in the question, that's why it was necessary to make the app bar transparent, so forcing a color here doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice the background image, answer updated accordingly